# TypeScriptの2つの値に対するユーザー定義型ガードについて

Tags: typescript

次のコードをTypeScriptPlaygroundで動かしてみたところ、
testFunc(a);
のところで、aがnullの可能性があるとして、型エラーになっていました。
この型エラーを解消するために、isValidにユーザー定義型ガード`a is string`のようなことを記載したいのですがどのように記載するとよいのかがわかりません。

ご存知の方、おられましたら、教えてください。

a に string | null の型ではなく、stringを割り当てたらそういうことは起きないですが、
実際には固定値ではないコードなので、string | null で変数が割り当たる部分は
そのままにしておきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

```
const isValid = ({a, b}: {a: string | null, b: string | null}): boolean => {
  if (!a) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!b) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const testFunc = (args: string) => {
  console.log(args);
}

const main = () => {
  const a: string | null = null;
  const b: string | null = "B";

  if (isValid({a, b})) {
    testFunc(a);
  } else {
    console.log("test");
  }

}
main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript のバージョンは、現時点の最新版である v4.9 という前提で解答します。

まず、第一に ユーザー定義の型ガード関数 (User-Defined Type Guard) は、戻り値の型が `foo is type` のような `Type predicate` でなくてはなりません。
また、述部で言及できるのは一つの引数についてだけとなり、 分割代入引数は使えなさそうです。
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html?#using-type-predicates

次に、 if 文で type predicate を使う場合、そのスコープ内の該当部分までのコードフローの中で取りうる、最も厳しい内容が使われます。
つまり、いくら型注釈していても、 `const a: string | null = null;` と書けば、 `a` の型は `null` なのです。
サンプルを書く場合は、（書き方は色々ありますが）そのスコープ単体では実行時まで値が決定しないように書くと良いでしょう。

また、 `{ a, b }` はあくまで `{ a: a, b: b }` の省略表記であり、このオブジェクトの `a` プロパティと `a` 変数は別物であるため、現状 `a` プロパティの型ガードの結果は `a` 変数に伝搬しなさそうです。

---

といったあたりを総合すると、提示されたコードの構造を保ったまま直すなら、以下となるでしょうか。

```
const isValid = (arg: any): arg is {a: string, b: string } => {
  if (!arg.a) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!arg.b) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const testFunc = (args: string) => {
  console.log(args);
}

const main = () => {
  const a: string | null = ["A", null][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  const b: string | null = ["B", null][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
  const tmp = { a, b };

  if (isValid(tmp)) {
    testFunc(tmp.a);
  } else {
    console.log("test");
  }

}
main();
```

ただ、これだと変数 `a`, `b` の書き方がクドいので、 `main` 関数周りは、以下のように書くほうがオススメです。

```
const main = (a: string | null, b: string | null) => {
  const tmp = { a, b };

  if (isValid(tmp)) {
    testFunc(tmp.a);
  } else {
    console.log("test");
  }

}
main(null, "B");
```

Comment: ユーザー定義の型ガード関数は、その関数内の実装が間違っていても、一切チェックがないため、意外にも非常に危険な処理です。複数のプロパティに跨がるような複雑なロジックを使うことはあまりオススメしません。 <https://zenn.dev/canalun/articles/safe_type_predicate> などを参考に、なるべく安全なロジックを書くよう心がけることをお勧めします。

Comment: お返事遅くなってしまいました。
とても勉強になりました。非常に丁寧にご説明いただき、ありがとうございます。

a, b それぞれを、isStringでチェックするほうが、TypeScriptとして自然で、コードとしてもきれいなので、そのように書くように心がけます。